# Uneven inflation of a new inner tube?

Tags: innertube, inflation

I bought a new inner tube and when I tried to inflate it, the tube got unevenly inflated (check picture). This is the first time I'm installing a tube by myself so I don't know if this is normal. Do you think this is this a production defect, or did I do something wrong while pumping the tube? Can I fix it by myself?

[image]

Comment: Normal. They are not designed to be inflated without a tire around them. Just use it.

Comment: Yes you did something wrong.  You are supposed to put the tube in the tire and mount it on the rim.

Comment: Yep, perfectly normal, if you over-inflate it that much.  The tube is not designed to hold pressure by itself, and will rarely allow more than about 5psi without ballooning out like that.

Comment: Okay all great, thanks. Now can somebody put this as a proper answer instead of comments so that I accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you did something wrong. You are supposed to put the tube in the tire and mount it on the rim.

If you inflate a balloon you will see similar behavior.  After you have stretched a tube IN the tire the behavior outside the tire will change slightly.

Comment: Andy you down voted.  Why?

Comment: It's a duplicate. Surely you would know that. New users don't learn to use the site as it's supposed to work if senior users such as yourself feed contrary behaviour.

Comment: @andy256 Feed contrary behavior?  By that logic your first comment without marking as a duplicate feed contrary behavior.

Comment: A comment is not an answer. I was on my phone and not able to check for duplicates at the time.

Comment: @andy256 Still a feed.  Cheers.   I hope the OP learned his/her lesson.